# Symfony 1.4 Doctrine run custom query give warnings

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I try to run following query as follows.

```
 $query = "DELETE FROM `ski_chalet_price` WHERE 1";    

 $conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->connection();
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute();
```

But it throws following warning.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/dinuka/workspace/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/database/sfDoctrineConnectionProfiler.class.php on line 196

Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/dinuka/workspace/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/database/sfDoctrineConnectionProfiler.class.php on line 141
```

This is query that i want to run.

```
INSERT INTO ski_chalet_price 
(ski_chalet_id, month, d_19,d_20,d_21,d_22,d_23,d_24,d_25,created_at) VALUES
(44,'2013-04-01',10,10,10,10,10,10,10,'2013-04-19 13:27:26') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
ski_chalet_id = 44, month = '2013-04-01',d_19 = 10,d_20 = 10,d_21 = 10,d_22 = 10,d_23 = 10,d_24 = 10,d_25 = 10, updated_at = '2013-04-19 13:27:26' ;
```

It is not depend on my query. Whats the issue?

Comment: Why do you need to run this kind of query using a raw query? Can't you done this using doctrine method?

Comment: No. Acctually i want run Upsert query. I mention simple query as example. This result is not depend query.

Comment: Could you then put the right query your are trying to perform? And also, what you are doing after

Comment: @j0k - it is not query problem. I update my question with sample query.

Comment: I know it's not a query problem, I would like to know what you do **after** the query, what you do **with** the query result.

Comment: I am trying to do a subselect and also have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I inspected the code on `sfDoctrineConnectionProfiler.class.php` and I found out that `execute();` needs an empty set of parameters (i.e. an empty array) in order not to complain.

So:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

should be:

```
$stmt->execute(array());
```

Note that the "join" word in the error is misleading.  It's not referring to a SQL join, but to PHP's native join() function which is an alias of implode().